# Как изменить TextField с другого фрейма?

Tags: java, javafx, listener

Пишу программу в которой вызывается 2й фрейм в котором происходит выбор папки.
При нажатии кнопки закрывается фрейм и путь передается в 1й фрейм в котором есть TextField для отображения пути. 
Вопрос в том что не могу настроить изменения поля постольку не могу вызиваться нон-статик переменные с других классов (хотел сделать изменение при нажатии потому что 1й фрейм не закрывается при открытии второго). 
Есть ли способ добавить лисенер (на изменение String пути или нажатии кнопки в другом фрейме) при котором я смогу поменять TextField.
Спасибо.

```
public class Controller {
    // First frame controller

    public static String path;
    public static String nickname;

    @FXML
    private TextField nicknameField;

    @FXML
    public TextField pathField;

    @FXML
    private Button changeDirButton;

    @FXML
    private Button submitButton;



    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        changeDirButton.setOnAction(event -> {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/dirs/dirs.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            Parent r = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Directories");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(r, 400, 310));
            stage.showAndWait();
        });
    }

}


//Метод высылки String в другой класс и закрытия фрейма

pathSubmitButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
    Controller.path = path;
    pathSubmitButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    System.out.println(Controller.path);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если действовать прямолинейно и в лоб, то:
после вызова `loader.load();` можно получить getController() вашего второго окна и имея его экземпляр передать в него `this` контроллер исходного окна, он и будет своего рода слушателем. А там уже дергайте нужные методы. Если программа небольшая, то подход имеет место быть, но такое может быстро превратиться в неконтролируемый хаос. Можно так же обыграть использование слушателей у Property fx типов и посмотреть в сторону EventBus